# how to know which http action called from rest client at server side

Tags: perl, rest, rest-client

When a request was made(actions like GET POST PATCH) to server through a rest client like LWP or REST::Client or HTTP::Request. how can we decode the request so that we will get the actual method which is called from client. if we can get the action we will process or respond to client accordingly.

this way i am able to get headers, all params sent in post request.

```
my $q = CGI->new;
my $input = $q->param( 'POSTDATA' ); # for content

my %headers = map { $_ => $q->http($_) } $q->http();

print $q->header('text/plain');
print "Got the following headers:\n";
    for my $header ( keys %headers ) {
        print "$header: $headers{$header}\n";
    }
```

Now my question is how to receive the action like GET or POST.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From [the docs](https://metacpan.org/pod/distribution/CGI/lib/CGI.pod#request_method)

> `request_method()`
>   Returns the method used to access your script, usually one of 'POST', 'GET' or 'HEAD'.

---

Also from the docs:

> CGI.pm is no longer considered good practice for developing web applications, including quick prototyping and small web scripts. There are far better, cleaner, quicker, easier, safer, more scalable, more extensible, more modern alternatives available at this point in time. These will be documented with [CGI::Alternatives](https://metacpan.org/pod/CGI::Alternatives).